# while updating the xml filed i gtting error like this

Tags: xquery

> SELECT failed because the following
>   SET options have incorrect settings:
>   'ARITHABORT'. Verify that SET options
>   are correct for use with indexed views
>   and/or indexes on computed columns
>   and/or query notifications and/or xml
>   data type methods.

Can anyone say what problem in the following statements

```
while(@CountOfFile>=@Inc)
begin
    SELECT  @FileName = Attachments.value('(/Files/File[@Id=sql:variable("@Inc")]/Name/text())[1]','nvarchar(50)')  FROM   MOD_Quiz where Id = @Id
    select @FilePath = Attachments.value('(/Files/File[@Id=sql:variable("@Inc")]/FilePath/text())[1]','nvarchar(50)')  FROM   MOD_Quiz where Id = @Id

  set   @Actual_Path  =  @FilePath  +  '/' +  @Id  + '/' + @FileName 
  set  @Inc=@Inc+1

  update MOD_Quiz set Attachments.modify('replace value of (/Files/File[@Id=sql:variable("@Inc")]/FilePath/text())[1] with sql:variable("@Actual_Path") ') where Id =@Id

end
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: If you use `SQL Server` please have a look at my answer on [Failed because incorrect arithabort setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140159/failed-because-incorrect-arithabort-setting/35750269#35750269) page. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: there's nothing wrong with your `SELECT` statements, but there's something wrong with your general [SET ARITHABORT setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190306%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

As [this article on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx) explains, for an indexed view or XML data type methods, you need to have `SET ARITHABORT ON`. So put that statement before yours and you should be fine.